# Phpstorm don't work after TortoiseSVN to 1.8 version upgradet

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, phpstorm

SVN worked fine, but i updated TortoiseSVN to 1.8 version and uprgraded the project (on new Tortoise). Now i have errors on phpstorm:
"Can't use Subversion command line client. Probably the path to Subversion executable is wrong" and 
"Errors found while svn working copies detection".

What i should make ?

I have tried File | Invalidate Caches.

Phpstorm 7.1.1

regards

Comment: have you specified a path to SVN command line client in Settings/version control/subversion? See the comments in http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117998 for possible hints

Answer (score 5):

You should ensure that "command line client tools" option is checked during installation of TortoiseSVN

Answer (score 4):

## install this package:

http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download

## config the phpstorm or other jetbrains ide:

file->settings->Version Contorl->subversion->with conmand line client
  set to "D:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\svn.exe"

preference: http://www.cnblogs.com/Deasel-s-magic-box/p/3492941.html

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for a solution to this issue in PHPstorm for a couple of days, and I found a clue (but not the solution) from fantaxy025025's answer.

PHPstorm showed me the path (C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin), and I confirmed that the path was in the Win10 system path variable and that svn.exe was in the \bin directory. Taking a cue from fantaxy025025, I went to File->Settings->Version Control->Subversion and added "\svn.exe" after the path. After I restarted PHPstorm, the error was gone and the SVN behaviors (e.g., after adding a new file) were back.